# How to get the last part of the current URL with react router v6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

How can I get the last part of the current url with react router v6?

For example:

If the current path is `https://localhost:4200/example/example-details`, then I want to check it like this

```
const location = useLocation();

if (location.pathname === '/example-details')) {
  // do some stuff here
}
```

..but this always returns the full path.

It works with `location.pathname.includes('/example-details')`, but I'm curious if there is a way with the react router, like it is possible with the Angular router..

Comment: It looks to me that one of [`useResolvedPath`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#useresolvedpath) or [`resolvePath`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#resolvepath) might help you normalize one or the other sides of your comparison.

Answer (score 5):

```
const location = useLocation();
const [pathName, setPathName] = useState(null) ;

useEffect(() => {
    if(location) {
        let tmp = location.pathName.slice(location.pathName.lastIndexOf("/") , location.pathName.length) ;
        setPathName(tmp) ;
    }
}, [location])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

```
const match = useMatch('/example/:lastPart')
const value = match?.props.lastPart;
if (!!value) {
    // do some stuff here
}
```

Using useMatch you can apply a template to your current location and extract some parts as props inside the returning object.

Answer (score 2):

check for

```
location.pathname.includes('/example-details')
```

Comment: I also changed my code like this. It works.

..so there is no way in react to get parts of the current URL with the react router? It was possible with the Angular router...

Answer (score 1):

```
import { useMatch } from "react-router-dom";

function MyComponent() {
  const match = useMatch("/:firstRoute/:secondRoute/*");
  const { firstRoute, secondRoute } = match.params;
  const lastRoute = match.params["*"];

  return (
    <div>
      <p>First route: {firstRoute}</p>
      <p>Second route: {secondRoute}</p>
      <p>Last route: {lastRoute}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the combination of `useResolvedPath` and `useMatch` like so:

```
    const basePath = useResolvedPath('..'); // to get the current path 1 level higher 
    const match = useMatch<'section', string>(`${basePath.pathname}/:section`);
    const lastPartOfTheURL = match.params.section;
```